# TableViewCell not displaying layout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, identifier, uitableview

Here's a question about tableViewCell. I am trying my hand at table views for the first time and trying to get my head around reusable cells etc. I have managed to get it working to some extent. I have a tableView that lives on a child view controller which is its delegate and data source.  Code for delegate:

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController ()

@property NSArray *titles;

@property NSArray *thumblenails;

@end

@implementation ChildViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title 1", @"Title 2", @"Title 3", @"Title 4",nil];

    self.thumblenails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Image1", @"Image2", @"Image3", @"Image4", nil];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return self.titles.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SimpleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

//  cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.thumblenails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I also have a SimpleTableViewCell.xib:

[image]

I have set the class on the identity inspector to SimpleTableViewCell and imported the SimpleTableViewCell.h file to my ChildViewController.h. I have also set the identifier to "cell" in the attributes inspector of the Table view cell, but here is the thing. As I am not getting the look I want for my cell, I have tried misspelling it and nothing has changed so clearly the identifier is not doing anything. When I run my app I get this:

[image]

So the array of images and titles are being loaded but not the actual cell size and labels that I set on the xib file for the cell. I have tried changing something in the cell, like the background color in the attributes inspector.

and on the xib it looks like this:

[image]

but when I run it:

[image]

I am guessing all this is because the cell identifier is not actually linked, but I thought I had done that in the line:

```
 SimpleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Am I missing some important coding in here, linking something in the xib, or is it just a typo? any suggestions greatly appreciated.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE1////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have tried the second suggestion and the result is this:

[image]

So, hopefully this will throw some light into what I am doing wrong?

Also, I have corrected the original text, when I change the color to green it's using the attributes inspector.

Thanks for your help.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have removed the lines:

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.thumblenails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Also, added the code:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

and the code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * (0.3);
}
```

Now my table looks like this:

[image]

So question now is how do I add the actual values of the original arrays of titles and images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the height of cell to get the exact same look in the nib file. use this delegate method to set height of cell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * (0.3);// 0.3 should be your aspect ratio for cell:
    // for cell.height/ cell.width in nib file.

}
```

Comment: This is given me a strange result I will update the question with a picture of it.

Comment: this is because of your constraints. Because you are not using both the `UIImageView` you added and `UILabel`. you put label to interface but you are using the label and imageview supplied by `UITableViewCell`. Get reference to your imageview and label from interface builder and set their text and image. probably they are all in the wrong places.

Comment: Ok I've done that and it's all fine but no images as they are declared as an array in ChildViewController. Would it be a good idea to make the SimpleTableViewCell.h the delegate?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand the problem. What do you mean by no images.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I have removed the lines: cell.textLabel.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.thumblenails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; that were populating the titles and the images but conflicting with the labels (see update 1). So now, thanks to the code you provided I have the right hight and the labels appear (see update 2), but how can I populate them with my data? many thanks

Comment: you should create properties of your labels and imageview in tableviewcell header. if you dont have these, create them from interface builder. for example in your `SimpleTableViewCell.h` file you  should have `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView` that is connected to your tableviewcell's imageview. and when filling tableview, you should write `[cell.myImageView setImage:...]`. all of these  should be made for labels also.

Comment: Yes. Thanks so much. Best set of answers ever.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register nib for cell identifier.
Put `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];` to `viewDidLoad` method.

And you can remove

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: By the way this answer was also right, but I can't give two answers as valid?